# extracting part of text from file in python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a collection of text files that are of the form:

```
Sponsor     : U of NC Charlotte
      U N C C Station
      Charlotte, NC  28223    704/597-2000

NSF Program : 1468      MANUFACTURING MACHINES & EQUIP
Fld Applictn: 0308000   Industrial Technology                   
          56        Engineering-Mechanical                  
Program Ref : 9146,MANU,
Abstract    :
          9500390  Patterson   This award supports a new concept in precision metrology,
          the Extreme Ultraviolet Optics Measuring Machine (EUVOMM).  The goals for this
          system when used to measure optical surfaces are a diameter range of 250 mm
          with a lateral accuracy of 3.3 nm rms, and a depth range of 7.5 mm w
```

there's more text above and below the snippet. I want to be able to do the following, for each text file:

store the NSF program, and Fld Applictn numbers in a list, and store the associated text in another list

so, in the above example I want the following, for the i-th text file:

```
y_num[i] = 1468, 0308000, 56
y_txt[i] = MANUFACTURING MACHINES & EQUIP, Industrial Technology, Engineering-Mechanical
```

Is there a clean way to do this in python? I prefer python since I am using os.walk to parse all the text files stored in subdirectories.

Comment: Depending on how consistent the format is you could either do this with regular expressions or simple string operations or by writing a parser. All of this is possible in python.

Comment: Yes, and string operations tend to be rather tedious if you do them alot. Although sometimes it is not that bad. See my answer for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file = open( "file","r")
for line in file.readlines():
    if "NSF" in line:
        values= line.split(":")
    elif "Fld" in line:
        values1 = line.split(":")
```

So values and values1 has the specific values which  you are intetested

Comment: with open(filename,'r') as f:
                for line in f.deadlines():          gives me :file object has no attribute deadlines"

Comment: Find the new code. That's actually readlines. Sorry. Autocorrect sucks sometime.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. I actually googled "deadlines" in the context of python file operations and it threw up garbage. never thought it was a typo ! Your solution works, in that I get the required fields. I have to strip the numbers and text from those lines separately, but that's very doable.  Also, else if --> elif .

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
yourtextlist = yourtext.split(':')
numbers = []
for slice in yourtextlist:
    l = slice.split()
    try:
        numbers.append(int(l[0]))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but it also saves EVERY number in the text. I'm specifically looking for the numbers corresponding to the fields mentioned above.